# Silently RDC with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

My goal is as follows: I need to be able to go in to one of our servers and run a script but I have to do this remotely through PowerShell. It needs to run silently - not require any user input. There is a username\password that I want to provide for the script along with an IP address.

I need to be able to RDC so that I can edit files on the server after a task has completed on Octopus.

Everything I have tried so far has required a password upon opening. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Right now I have this: New-PSSession -ComputerName 100.100.10.100 -Credential Code1\name
I'm aware that this will prompt for a password but was wondering if there was a way around this or if there is another type of command that I should be using.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think that we will need more details. What command is prompting for a password?

Comment: Why RDC in when you could connect using PS Remoting and check the files with PowerShell?

Comment: Ben, it doesn't really matter whether or not I use PsRemoting or not. I have been trying to use a new PSSession but it still prompts me for the password which will be an issue with automation. Right now I have this: New-PSSession  -ComputerName 100.100.10.100 -Credential Code1\name

Comment: Well, first of all you haven't really clrified what exactly is prompting for credentials. Second, if you have more information about your question you should edit the question to include the information not put it in a comment. Third. the command that you have shown does not pass the password to the New-PSSession cmdlet so yes you would be prompted. Look at the Get-Credential cmdlet.

Comment: Yes, there is a way around the credential prompt. Use Get-Credential to create a credential object including password that you pass to New-PSSession. Of course this generally involves putting the password into the script which is not the most secure thing in the world to do.

Comment: I am aware that get-credential prompts for a password. My question is whether or not there is a way around a the prompt, or any way in general to connect to another server (hence why I didn't specify I was trying PsRemoting in the first place because I highly doubt that's the correct solution to my problem). I'm fairly new at using Stack Overflow so forgive me for putting my response in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you EBGreen. I was thinking some kind of hash for the password

Comment: Any way taht you encode the password to put it into the script can be decoded by anyone that has access to the script. Security by obfuscation is not security.

Comment: This is not touchy information that I am using, nor is my environment a security risk but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a credential object,

```
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName,$Password
New-PSSession -Credential $Credential -computerName $computer
```

Get the `$Username` and `$Password` using Parameters, `$Password` will be of type `[system.Security.SecureString`